# JSF inputTextArea valueChangeListener

Tags: ajax, jsf, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

Is there any way to force firing of valueChangeListener during typing into an  component?

I am trying to simply count the number of chars user has entered in the textArea without resorting to JavaScript coding, but it simply won't budge.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<ice:inputTextarea maxlength="4000" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;" 
value="#{controller.remarkText}"
valueChangeListener="#{controller.updateTextCount}" />

<ice:inputText readonly="true" size="3" maxlength="4" value="#{controller.remarkTextCharCount}" />
```

We're using IceFaces 1.8.2 and JSF 1.2.

Comment: Use Javascript, The valueChangeListener event fired when you press enter or when the text-area loses the focus and your case required on key up event to be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding partialSubmit="true" , that said however it would be submitting every character to the server and that is not an ideal solution. A simple javascript based validation is valid for this use case.

Cheers!